# ТГ бот, который пересылает сообщения другому пользователю

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Новичок в данной сфере
Необходимо реализовать следующее:
Когда пользователь вводит команду /feedback, бот сначала должен выдать сообщение(Готов принять ваш отзыв:), после - получить ответ и его же переслать по owner_id, и выдать (Спасибо, отзыв был отправлен).
У меня же, после /feedback бот выводит 2 сообщения одновременно, и более того, все последующие сообщение также отправляет по owner_id

```
import config
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
owner_id = ''


    
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    message_text = 'Здравствуйте, '  + message.from_user.first_name + "!" \
                    + '\nЯ Бот-отзовик.\nГотов принять ваш отзыв. \n/feedback - оставить отзыв'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
@bot.message_handler(commands=["feedback"])
def feedback(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Готов принять ваш отзыв: ")

    bot.forward_message(owner_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, отзыв был отправлен ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

используй next step handler

```
import config
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
owner_id = 'ваш айди'



@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    message_text = 'Здравствуйте, '  + message.from_user.first_name + "!" + '\nЯ Бот-отзовик.\nГотов принять ваш отзыв. \n/feedback - оставить отзыв'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["feedback"])
def feedback(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Готов принять ваш отзыв: ")
    # устанавливаем следующий шаг обработки сообщения
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, feedback_second) # передаем старое сообщение и функцию, в которой будем обрабатывать

    
def feedback_second(message):
    bot.forward_message(owner_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, отзыв был отправлен ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но после копирования вашего кода, у меня выдает огромную ошибку. Видимо чего-то не хватает

Comment: @Илья какая ошибка?

Comment: @ДанилаГраф *после копирования вашего кода* - звучит так, как будто  вы вообще ничего не поменяли. Подставьте ваш токен и заполните `owner_id`. И еще, лучше спрячьте ваш токен из вопроса, если не хотите обнаружить странные действия с вашим ботом в будущем)

Comment: @Стас единственная ошибка, которая у меня появилась - не совсем корректный перенос строки, который легко можно поправить. в самом коде ошибок нет